# How to determine AAC bit depth

Tags: ffmpeg, aac, 16-bit

With a `wav` file for example you can easily distinguish between [**bit depths**](http://wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_bit_depth)

24-bit

```
Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s24le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 44100 Hz, stereo, 
                    s32, 2116 kb/s
```

16-bit

```
Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 44100 Hz, stereo,
                    s16, 1411 kb/s
```

However AAC seems inscrutable

```
Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo,
                         fltp, 151 kb/s
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

ffprobe reports correct bit depth but only **when there is a bit depth to report**, otherwise it reports correctly that "bit-depth" is not applicable (N/A).

In FFmpeg's report of the data field "bits_per_raw_sample" and [per Karans answer](https://superuser.com/a/553559/630402), "bit-depth" is misnomer for AAC encoded audio.

If you are trying to probe the data file, you might want to `grep -e` for "codec_name" to discern which streams (video, audio, text) the "bits_per_raw_sample" is reporting. This makes it easy to know if the reported bit-depth status pertains to the video codec or the audio codec:

```
$ ffprobe -show_streams <input_file.mp4> | grep -e codec_name -e bits_per_raw_sample
```

...example of a resulting video and audio datafile report:

```
codec_name=h264           <----- video
bits_per_raw_sample=8     <----- 8-bit depth video
codec_name=aac            <----- AAC audio
bits_per_raw_sample=N/A   <----- bit depth is "Not Applicable" to AAC audio
```

You might enjoy this article, "[Audio Encoding Demystified](https://www.epiphan.com/blog/audio-encoding-demystified/)"

> Bit depth
>
> Along with sample rate, there is also bit depth to consider. The bit
>   depth is the number of digital bits of information used to encode each
>   sample. In simple terms, bit depth measures “precision”. The higher
>   the bit depth, the more accurately a signal can communicate the
>   amplitude of the actual analog sound source. With the lowest possible
>   bit depth, we only have two choices to measure the precision of sound:
>   0 for complete silence and 1 for full volume. The higher the bit
>   depth, the more precision one has over their encoded audio. As an
>   example: CD quality audio is a standard 16-bit, which gives 216 (or
>   65,536) volumes to choose from.
>
> Bit depth is fixed for PCM encoding, but **for lossy compression
>   codecs (like MP3 and AAC) it is calculated during encoding and can
>   vary from sample to sample.**

...so, to address the question, "How to determine AAC bit depth?" I suppose you'd have to do it on a sample per sample basis.

Comment: *for lossy compression codecs (like MP3 and AAC) it is calculated during encoding and can vary from sample to sample* -> there will still be a ceiling on the bit depth. If a MP3 is encoded from a 16-bit PCM source, then one wouldn't expect 24-bit precision upon decoding.

Comment: @Mulvya, ffmpeg is in ongoing development. If you want to, you could author an feature for ffmpeg which analyzed each sample's bit depth and reported that range, however, "bits_per_raw_sample" is not a constant integer with AAC and the authors of ffmpeg have seen fit to address this standard of digital audio by reporting that the term "bit-depth" is "not applicable" (N/A) to AAC files.

Comment: @Mulvya, likewise, it could be useful to know the range, but I don't really see how except in edge cases and what would be gained by calculating the entire range as part of a meta-data print out? FFmpeg is built for speed. Like i said, tho, this option could be added as a feature if and when you want ffmpeg to report such, however, for the industry standards "bit-depth" is misnomer for describing AAC files.

Comment: @Mulvya to be clear, you make a valid and sound point. If you deem the question or answer useful, please vote accordingly. Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

[AAC](//wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Audio_Coding) is a lossy format (like MP3), and as [Wikipedia](//wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_bit_depth) (indeed, the same
article you linked to) explains:

> Bit depth is only meaningful in reference to a PCM digital signal. Non-PCM
> formats, such as lossy compression formats, do not have associated bit depths.
> For example, in MP3, quantization is performed on PCM samples that have been
> transformed into the frequency domain.

Answer (score 2):

Truth that those formats are not exactly bit size per sample, but you can take an approximation by having in mind two variables: sample rate and bitrate.

If you know that the sample rate means how many samples per second (for example if you have 44100 Hz, that means that 1 second 44100 samples are played) and the bitrate (in my case is 95kb/s) then you know that 95000 bytes/second divided by 44100 samples/second = 2.1542 (approximately) bytes/sample.
That are a bit more than a 16-bit quality encoding. So, you can decode greatly to 24 bits per raw sample at 44100Hz, with the following command of ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4a -acodec pcm_s24le -f s24le -ar 44.1k -ac 2 out.pcm
```

It won't be exactly 24 bits so it may be oversized, but you won't lose quality if you convert to a lower quality.

Comment: Also, if you want to know the coding information, you can use just: ffmpeg -i input.mp4a instead of ffprobe.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Before answering an old question having an accepted answer (look for green ✓) as well as other answers ensure your answer adds something new or is otherwise helpful in relation to them. Here is a guide on [answer]. There is also a site [tour] and  a [help].

Comment: The answer gives a tip but not a clear example, so my answer adds a suitable information.